Searching for an illustrated children's book with anthropomorphic animals, a sled, and a train
When I was little, we had two small books that I cannot remember the names of. The stories were set in a winter scene with pine trees and snow, the main characters were (three?) anthropomorphic animals — possibly a fox, rabbit, or hedgehog, maybe it was also a mouse I cant remember. I also recall a sled being part of the story and a red locomotive that they found. My brother remembers additional details, like a hot air balloon and a carriage. The books had white pages with colored illustrations that gradually faded into the white background, accompanied by text. My brother thinks the title was something like "Bla Bla and the Red Locomotive" but we haven’t been able to find anything by that name. We had the books in German, but they might also exist in other languages.
It is definitely not a new story. The books were very thin and the main characters (fox or rabbit, not sure and some friends) were clothed, I remember the fashion style as British in the direction of Sherlock Holmes. I am sure it is a children's book but it is not a trivial story, it is a nice little story even for older children.
The book's style was not that the whole page is an image and in between there is text. It's a picture per page and below or above there is the text, like in a novel.

After almost 2 hours of research, by luck, I was able to find it. In german it is called
Geschichten aus dem Wald der Füchse, Band 1: Der rote Fuchs.

Those are books by Cynthia and Brian Paterson.
The stories are set in the picturesque and idyllic village of Foxwood, inhabited by anthropomorphic animal characters, primarily foxes, rabbits, and mice. Exactly what I was searching for. The train I mentioned is the red fox in the german title.

Please [edit] this answer with a description of how it matches the question. For example, you could include quotes or pictures of the elements that you mention in the question. This would help people who find the question later, as they could confirm whether the book matches what they remember.

The style of colorful anthropomorphic animal characters on a white background sounds like the children's author Richard Scarry. I see a couple of winter-themed books:

Richard Scarry's Busy Busy Winter has a cover depicting a winter scene with clothed animals skiing, sledding, and playing hockey. There is a red snowplow tractor.
Winter Tales by Kathryn Jackson, illustrated by Richard Scarry has a whitish (snowy?) cover depicting various animals wearing winter pajamas and reading books. The characters somewhat fade into the white background.

Scarry was born in the USA, and he lived in German-speaking town of Gstaad, Switzerland, for the last 20+ years of his life. He is one of the most prolific and widely-read children's book authors. It's not entirely unlikely that his books would be published in German.

Thanks for the answer, but those are sadly not the ones.

I will give you a +1 for your help and for the recommendations!
